# Getting a facebook place's profile picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble getting the profile picture for place, I tried the normal method for getting user or page profile pictures

`https://graph.facebook.com/[ID]/picture?width=150&height=150`

but get the following error:-

`"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (picture) on node type (PlaceInformation)"`

I can get the cover photo by doing the following API call

`/GET/v7.0/[place_id]?fields=cover`

The PlaceInformation node does not mention any way to get the profile picture, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but spent way to long on this already!

Cheers for any pointers.

Comment: PlaceInformation has a `location` property, that points to the page for the place, and _that_ has a profile picture. (But your app will need to have the Page Public Content Access feature approved, before you can get any information from these location pages.)

Comment: When I query the location property the ID it returns is the same as the ID in the query i'm executing:-
`[SAME_ID]?fields=location`
returns:-
```{
  "location": {
    "city": "...",
    "country": "...",
    "latitude": ...,
    "longitude":...,
    "street": "...",
    "zip": "..."
  },
  "id": "[SAME_ID]"
}```

Comment: The Place Information object also has a `page` property, could be that’s what provides the profile picture.